# Looking for text editor with multiple functionalities

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm building a web app; front-end in Angular and back-end in Ruby on Rails.

I need to achieve below functionalities. I am basically adding text editor so users can edit template letters in my service.

```
1) Load .doc file from the file system(or remote server) to the text editor
2) Edit the loaded .doc file and save the file as different name
```

Is there any recommendable free text editor which can achieve those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try this one ?

http://textangular.com/

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've looked into this but there's no any guide talking about loading file and saving file using the text editor. Do  you know anything about this?

Comment: No sorry, I dont think you can load a file from this module..